# What do double curly braces mean in systemd scripts?

Tags: python, systemd, virtualenv

A stackoverflow answer about running python scripts upon system startup uses `{{` and `}}` in its syntax. What do they mean?

`ExecStart={{ venv_home }}/bin/fooservice --serve-in-foreground`

I am also not clear where `venv_home` comes from. I can't find it as any predefined variable and I can't imagine systemd has any knowledge about python virtual envs.

Here is the answer that I am struggling to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37211676/2297550

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The curly braces mean nothing to systemd. The other question was either using them as a placeholder for a variable name or using some kind of template to generate systemd files.

Answer (score 5):

In the linked example, `{{ venv_home }}` is a general placeholder for the location of the virtual environment in question ([venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)). For example, this could be `/home/pi/yourproject`. The double-curly-brace notation appears a bit flamboyant, which may have added to the confusion.